# How to select All the rows from first table and get count of all the matching rows from other table for each row retrived from first table

Tags: mysql, join

Following are the tables

Table 1

```
price     col1     col2     time
10        1        1        10
100       1        1        13
150       1        1        15
```

Table 2

```
id     startTm     endTm     col1     col2
1      12          20        1        1
2      15          26        1        1
3      11          13        1        1
```

I want all the rows from table 2 satisfying startTm >= x and endTm <= y. And for each row in result I want to find count of all the records in table 1 where table1.time lies in startTm and endTm for that particular row

Something like this-

```
SELECT (@sTime:=T2.startTm) AS startTm,JT.totalNo, JT.totalPrice, 
(@eTime:=T2.endTm) AS endTm 
some more columns FROM table 2 AS T2
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(id) AS totalNo,col1, col2 SUM(price) AS 
  totalPrice FROM table 1 WHERE time BETWEEN @sTime AND @eTime GROUP 
  BY col1, col2)
  AS JT ON JT.col1 = T2.col1
WHERE T2.startTm >= some value AND T2.endTm <= some value.
```

There are no related foreign keys.I Am not getting proper results. How is it done?

**Edit**

I want all the records from table 2 within specified time range suppose startTm >= 10 to endTm<=20 
so output table will be

```
startTm     endTm     totalNo     totalPrice     some more col
12          20        2           250            ...
11          13        1           100            ...
```

to calculate total Price and total number I want to consider startTm and endTime of that particular row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT startTm, endTm, COUNT(price), SUM(price), t3_others, t1_others
FROM
(
  SELECT T3.startTm AS startTm, T3.endTm AS endTm, T3.others AS t3_others, T1.price AS price, T1.others AS t1_others
  FROM T1
  RIGHT JOIN
  (
    SELECT T2.startTm, T2.endTm, T2.others
    FROM T2
    WHERE T2.startTm >= 10 AND T2.endTm <= 20 AND T2.col1 = col1_value AND T2.col2 = col2_value
  ) AS T3
  ON T1.time >= T3.startTm AND T1.time <= T3.endTm
) AS T4
GROUP BY startTm, endTm;
```

Add other more fields as you need.

Comment: Updated my question for better understanding. Please have a look @walter

Comment: I want sum of all the prices from table 1 whose time falls in between start time and end time of already retrived row from table 2.

Comment: I've adjusted my query. Try it please.

Comment: It is working but I am not able to select more columns from table 2 coz they arent aggregated.

Comment: Just add one more `SELECT` outside the previous query, then group by startTm and endTm, you'll get what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the help. One more question. This query is not listing rows from table 2 which matches criteria but dont have any matching records in table 1. It should show count 0.

Comment: Change `JOIN` to `RIGHT JOIN`, and you will get these rows. I've changed my query.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Query:

Select t1.* , t2.* from Table 1 as t1  RIGHT JOIN  Table 2 as t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 WHERE t2.startTm >= 'your value' AND t2.endTm <= 'your value'